# ImageMagick: get image size with respect to EXIF orientation

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-identify

I know that `convert` can use `-auto-orient` parameter to correctly rotate image when resizing it but can I somehow get image's rotated size with respect to EXIF orientation using `identify`?

Comment: Can you post one for folks to experiment with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The -auto-orient option is not supported by identify so you will have to use the convert command. With the code below you can get the dimensions of your image:

```
// If you only need the width and height
convert -auto-orient image.jpg -format %wx%h info:

// If you want the same result as identify
convert -auto-orient image.jpg info:
```